# Can not drop to send file to the simulator on M2 Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I always drop a file to the simulator and it will be saved into the Files app of the simulator. But on an M2 Mac, the operation always fails and it shows the error:

> Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation

How can I fix it? Or is there another way to send a file to the simulator on an M2 Mac?

[image]